# IPV4 traffic not working with AWS egress only internet gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipv6, ipv4, private-subnet

I have assigned an egress only internet gateway to my private subnet. Now I can connect with IPV6 websites but not with IPV4 addresses.

Do I need NAT gateways to access IPV4 address from my EC2 machine? (Only outgoing traffic)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need either a [NAT Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html), or simply an [Internet Gateway](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Internet_Gateway.html). But if you are only interested in outgoing, then a NAT Gateway is the way to go.

Egress only internet gateways are for IPv6 only. As mentioned [in the documentation for them](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/egress-only-internet-gateway.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a `NAT Gateway` to access `IPv4` websites from your EC2 instance in private subnet.

To make the instance in private subnet to access both `IPv4` and `IPv6` websites, we need:

- NAT Gateway (Only `IPv4` outgoing traffic)
- Egress Only Internet Gateway (Only `IPv6` outgoing traffic)

Don't forget to assign an `IPv6 address` to the instance in private subnet otherwise the instance cannot access `IPv6` websites.

*A `public IPv4 address` is not needed for the instance in private subnet. We can access `IPv4` websites without it.

Moreover, with the commands below, we can check if the connections to `IPv4` and `IPv6` websites are available from the instance in private subnet.

For IPv4 websites:

```
ping -4 google.com
```

For IPv6 websites:

```
ping -6 google.com
```